# Prevent duplication in Repeating Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, static-code-analysis, spring-scheduled

[Repeating Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html) as [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) allow multiple annotations

But it also allows duplicated values in different annotation which can cause unexpected results

Simple example using [Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) with duplicated fixedRate values:

```
private static final long TIME = 1000 * 60 * 1L; // 1 minute
private static final long TIME2 = 1000 * 60 * 1L; // 1 minute
@Scheduled(fixedRate = TIME)
@Scheduled(fixedRate = TIME2)
public synchronized void refresh() {
```

It will execute twice per minute the schedule task instead of once

Is there a a way to avoid using duplicated value in repeated annotation?

Is there any rule (or can I suggest new rule) in sonar or other static code analysis tool?

Comment: How is that behavior unexpected? That is exactly what I would expect from a method with these annotations

Comment: @OhleC Maybe behavior isn't obvious, but can I define such annotations with ignoring duplicated values?

Comment: I don't see anything like that in the API. And I think that's probably a good choice, since it may actually be a valid use of a repeated annotation. You could just filter out annotations with repeated values while processing annotations.