# How to create multiple instances of a scheduler class in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduling, spring-scheduled

I have a class containing the `@Scheduled` annotated method.
I want to create multiple instances of a class in spring boot application so that I should be able to run multiple jobs for the specified time period.

I have googled and tried with creating a new object but scheduling didn't work.

Note: I will pass what to execute at runtime for respective instance.

Comment: Have you added @EnableScheduling to your config? Also, some code might be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,
 I implemented `ApplicationContextAware`

```
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    for (int i =0;i<4;i++) {
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory()
        .registerSingleton("New Instance " + i, new SchedularJob());
    }
}
```

It will create 4 instances of SchedularJob class and 4 schedulers will run independently.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class with multiple methods to schedule your jobs at same time, doing same job..

```
@Component
public class Job {

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void job1() {
        jobWork();
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 60000)
    public void job2() {
        jobWork();
    }

    private void jobWork() {

    }
}
```

Comment: That will work, but remember about two things: `@EnableScheduling` annotation for configuration (can be in the main class) and also `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=X` in your `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

[@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) is a repatable annotation so you can add multiple `@Scheduled` in same method:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 60000)   
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000, fixedDelay = 60000)
public void jobWork() {
    jobWork();
}
```

> @Repeatable(value=Schedules.class)

See also [Duplication on @Scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061630/prevent-duplication-in-repeating-annotations)

> Repeating Annotations as @Scheduled allow multiple annotations

Comment: Its a good approach but i need multiple instances of a single schedular